# Grant additional privilege to impersonating thread

Tags: windows, impersonation, shared-directory, virtual-disk

My program, "UP", needs to be able to mount VHDX files from network locations. The difficulty is that any thread calling `OpenVirtualDisk(...)` upon a network location needs to have **both** `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE`, which most of my users will not have, **and** access to the network location, which any System process "SP" I install to get around this will not have.

Method 1: I've read I can have SP receive the user's credentials and use "client impersonation" to create a thread running as the user. But I don't know how to have SP also grant that thread `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE`.

Method 2: If SP is handed the user's credentials, can it use them to set up transparent access for itself to the network share, so that it can call `OpenVirtualDisk(...)` itself?

Comment: I think I'm going with Method 2. I'll just pre-authenticate to the share using the user's credentials.

Comment: Ooh, I'm possibly wrong: The same thread does not need both permissions at the same time. One thread can obtain the `HANDLE` to the VHDX by calling `OpenVirtualDisk`, which only requires authenticating to the network share. Another thread can (I think) pass that `HANDLE` to AttachVirtualDisk, which only requires `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_PRIVILEGE`.